# Comparar una variable tipo string con una variable tipo char[]

Tags: c++, winapi

Necesito hacer un programa donde el usuario pueda iniciar sesión y registrarse con un nombre y contraseña, dichos datos deben guardarse en un archivo de texto al ser registrados. Cada vez que el usuario ejecuta el programa debe ingresar sus datos, si coinciden con los datos guardados en el archivo de texto, lo dejara iniciar sesión, del caso contrario le indicara error. Y ese es mi problema, no se como hacer que se comparen los datos recién ingresados con los guardados en el archivo de texto para saber si coinciden o no.

````
#include "resource.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct datos {
    char nombre[256];
    char contrasena[256];
    datos* siguiente;
}usuario;

HWND hEDIT1;
HWND hEDIT2;
HWND caja;
datos *nuevo, *primero, *ultimo;
ofstream archivo;

BOOL CALLBACK MiCALLback(HWND ventana, UINT mensaje, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM IParam) {

    switch (mensaje) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: {
        hEDIT1 = GetDlgItem(ventana, IDC_EDIT1);
        hEDIT2 = GetDlgItem(ventana, IDC_EDIT2);
        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDOK: { //Inicar Sesion

            GetWindowText(hEDIT1, usuario.nombre, 256);
            GetWindowText(hEDIT2, usuario.contrasena, 256);

            string name, contraseña;
            ifstream archivo;
            archivo.open("usuario.txt", ios::in);
            if (archivo.fail()) {
                MessageBox(NULL, "Error al buscar usuarios", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                exit(1);
            }
            while (archivo.good()) {
                archivo >> name;
                if (!archivo.eof()) {
                    getline(archivo, contraseña);
                    /*MessageBox(NULL, "Usuario", ":D", MB_OK);*/
                    //If de comparacion
                }
            }
            archivo.close();
            EndDialog(ventana, NULL);
            break;
        }
        case IDCANCEL: { //Registrarse
            GetWindowText(hEDIT1, usuario.nombre, 256);
            GetWindowText(hEDIT2, usuario.contrasena, 256);

            archivo.open("usuario.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
            archivo << usuario.nombre << " " << usuario.contrasena << endl;
            archivo.close();

            EndDialog(ventana, NULL);
            break;
        }
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_CLOSE: { //Boton x de la ventana
        DestroyWindow(ventana);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: { //Cuando se destruye la ventana
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE a, HINSTANCE b, LPSTR c, int d)
{
    DialogBox(a, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, MiCALLback);
    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el operador de comparación:

```
if (name == usuario.nombre)
{
}
```

Hasta C++17, lo que sucederá aquí es que se creará un `std::string` temporal con el contenido de `usuario.nombre` y a continuación se comparará el contenido de ambos objetos. A partir de C++20 y el objeto temporal ya no será necesario pues ya existe una sobrecarga del operador que recibe un array de caracteres en el lado derecho.

Comment: Creo que lo había intentado pero igual no daba resultado, de todas formas ya pude resolver el problema, muchas gracias